# Is there any liquid in the bone medullary cavity

Tags: bone-biology

I am looking at the effect of intramedullary nails on tibial bones and can't seem to find anything on fluids present within the medullar cavity/canal. Since this is where blood cells are formed I would expect there to be at least a bit of blood in the cavity. I also read somewhere about something called 'liquid bone marrow'. Can someone please confirm whether there is blood in the cavity and whether there are any other fluids present. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bone marrow is almost a liquid.

Comment: @JM97 so there is a liquid and a solid component (spongy tissue). but what is the liquid composed of then?